# Google Cloud Drupal - Add new module authentication

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-modules, google-cloud-platform

I am using a drupal installation(click-to-deploy) on google cloud. With the clean installation I can add modules by going to "Install new module", entering the url of the package and then pressing the Install button.

But when I install a theme I purchased (by copying over the sites/all and sites/default directory and restoring a saved backup) and try the same steps I get taken to the Update manager (authorize.php) page. It also asks for my ftp information. A warning displays "WARNING: You are not using an encrypted connection, so your password will be sent in plain text. Learn more."

Obviously the files I copied over changed some settings but I am not sure which ones.

Any suggestions on what to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the messages in drupal weren't helpful I solved it by changing the user/group to www-data for all the directory+files.